# ASP.NET MVC 4 Read Persistent Auth Cookie Event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, forms-authentication, claims-based-identity

I'm using WebSecurity for Authentication and a custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` for Authorization.

Mixing Claims based authorization with the built in WebSecurity features for Authentication has provided me with a ton of value. I highly recommend it for anyone who requires complex authorization logic combining from several systems.

Anyways, everything is working great except the RememberMe feature.

When a user logs in, I set my auth cookie (via WebSecurity), new up my `ClaimsPrincipal`, and write it to my `SessionSecurityToken`. Bam, it works brilliantly.

However, when a user has previously elected to persist the (Websecurity) auth cookie, she is allowed to bypass my login method, which news up my `ClaimsPrincipal` and writes my principal to my `SessionSecurityToken`. My authorization fails because my claims haven't been loaded, because I haven't had a chance to transform my `ClaimsPrincipal`.

**Is there a way to hook into a (Websecurity) "forms authentication cookie read" event?** If so, I could handle it, new up my `ClaimsPrincipal`, and be on my way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (authorized)
        {
            httpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(...)
        }

        return authorized;
    }
}
```

Now decorate your protected controller actions with this custom attribute instead of the default built-in:

```
[MyAUthorize]
public ActionResult Protected()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Darin, nice one. What if i am blocking everything by default with a Global filter, and I white-list with 'AllowAnonymous' for the Login controller only? I guess the same principle, in the FilterConfig class i would register filters.Add(new MyAUthorizeAttribute()) . Correct ?